# Flutter : Horizontally and Vertically Scrolling Time Table with two sided header

Tags: flutter, dart, gridview, scroll, scrollview

In my flutter application I want to create a timetable widget as below which will scroll horizontally and vertically with corresponding heading. The timetable should have 'Day' as horizontal heading and 'Period' as vertical heading. During horizontal scrolling the 'Period' header should freeze and horizontal 'Day' header should scroll with data. Similarly, during vertical scrolling the 'Day' header should freeze and vertical 'Period' header should scroll with data. How can I achieve a widget like that.Please help..

In Android we can obtain the above type of scrolling by extending HorizontalScrollView & VerticalScrollView.

[image: Original]
[image: Scrolling horizontally]
[image: Scrolling Vertically]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Scrolling widgets will create a default scroll controller (ScrollController class) if none is provided. A scroll controller creates a ScrollPosition to manage the state specific to an individual Scrollable widget.

To link our scroll controllers we’ll use linked_scroll_controller, a scroll controller that allows two or more scroll views to be in sync.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:linked_scroll_controller/linked_scroll_controller.dart';

class ScrollDemo extends StatefulWidget {
@override
_ScrollDemoState createState() => _ScrollDemoState();
}

class _ScrollDemoState extends State<ScrollDemo> {
final List<String> colEntries = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ".split('');
final List<String> rowEntries =
    Iterable<int>.generate(15).map((e) => e.toString()).toList();

late LinkedScrollControllerGroup _horizontalControllersGroup;
late ScrollController _horizontalController1;
late ScrollController _horizontalController2;

late LinkedScrollControllerGroup _verticalControllersGroup;
late ScrollController _verticalController1;
late ScrollController _verticalController2;

@override
void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _horizontalControllersGroup = LinkedScrollControllerGroup();
    _horizontalController1 = _horizontalControllersGroup.addAndGet();
    _horizontalController2 = _horizontalControllersGroup.addAndGet();
    _verticalControllersGroup = LinkedScrollControllerGroup();
    _verticalController1 = _verticalControllersGroup.addAndGet();
    _verticalController2 = _verticalControllersGroup.addAndGet();
}

@override
void dispose() {
    _horizontalController1.dispose();
    _horizontalController2.dispose();
    _verticalController1.dispose();
    _verticalController2.dispose();
    super.dispose();
}

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
    appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('sync scroll demo'),
    ),
    body: SafeArea(
        child: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(20),
        child: Column(
            children: <Widget>[
            Row(
                children: <Widget>[
                Container(
                    width: 75,
                    height: 75,
                    color: Colors.grey[200],
                ),
                const SizedBox(width: 10),
                Container(
                    height: 75,
                    width: 400,
                    color: Colors.blue[100],
                    child: SingleChildScrollView(
                    scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                    controller: _horizontalController2,
                    child: HeaderContainer(rowEntries: rowEntries),
                    ),
                )
                ],
            ),
            const SizedBox(height: 10),
            Row(
                children: <Widget>[
                Container(
                    width: 75,
                    height: 400,
                    color: Colors.blue[100],
                    child: SingleChildScrollView(
                    controller: _verticalController2,
                    child: ColumnContainer(
                        colEntries: colEntries,
                    ),
                    ),
                ),
                const SizedBox(width: 10),
                SizedBox(
                    width: 400,
                    height: 400,
                    child: SingleChildScrollView(
                    controller: _verticalController1,
                    child: SingleChildScrollView(
                        scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                        controller: _horizontalController1,
                        child: BodyContainer(
                        rowEntries: rowEntries,
                        colEntries: colEntries,
                        ),
                    ),
                    ),
                )
                ],
            ),
            ],
        ),
        ),
    ),
    );
}
}

class ColumnContainer extends StatelessWidget {
final List<String> colEntries;
const ColumnContainer({
    Key? key,
    required this.colEntries,
}) : super(key: key);

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    int numberOfRows = colEntries.length;
    return Column(
    children: List.generate(
        numberOfRows,
        (i) {
        return Container(
            height: 75,
            width: 75,
            decoration: BoxDecoration(border: Border.all(color: Colors.white)),
            child: Center(child: Text(colEntries[i])),
        );
        },
    ),
    );
}
}

class HeaderContainer extends StatelessWidget {
final List<String> rowEntries;
const HeaderContainer({
    Key? key,
    required this.rowEntries,
}) : super(key: key);

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    int _numberOfColumns = rowEntries.length;
    return Row(
    children: List.generate(
        _numberOfColumns,
        (i) {
        return Container(
            height: 75,
            width: 75,
            decoration: BoxDecoration(border: Border.all(color: Colors.white)),
            child: Center(child: Text(rowEntries[i])),
        );
        },
    ),
    );
}
}

class BodyContainer extends StatelessWidget {
final List<String> colEntries;
final List<String> rowEntries;
const BodyContainer({
    Key? key,
    required this.colEntries,
    required this.rowEntries,
}) : super(key: key);

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    int _numberOfColumns = rowEntries.length;
    int _numberOfLines = colEntries.length;
    return Column(
    children: List.generate(_numberOfLines, (y) {
        return Row(
        children: List.generate(_numberOfColumns, (x) {
            return TableCell(item: "${colEntries[y]}${rowEntries[x]}");
        }),
        );
    }),
    );
}
}

class TableCell extends StatelessWidget {
final String item;
const TableCell({
    Key? key,
    required this.item,
}) : super(key: key);

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
    height: 75,
    width: 75,
    decoration: BoxDecoration(border: Border.all(color: Colors.grey)),
    child: Center(child: Text(item)),
    );
}
}
```

I found these solutions from these 2 links.

[Flutter: How to create linked scroll widgets](https://pjbelo.medium.com/flutter-how-to-create-linked-scroll-widgets-136f2dd078d4)

[Flutter: Creating a two-direction scrolling table with a fixed head and column](https://medium.com/nerd-for-tech/flutter-creating-a-two-direction-scrolling-table-with-fixed-head-and-column-4a34fc01378f)

Answer (score 3):

You can archive this using nested `listView` widgets.

You can try this approach:

```
class TimeTableView extends StatefulWidget {
  const TimeTableView({super.key});

  @override
  State<TimeTableView> createState() => _TimeTableViewState();
}

class _TimeTableViewState extends State<TimeTableView> {
  final periodsSlots = 15;

  final double containerHeight = 55.0;

  final double containerWidth = 80;

  final days = [
    "Monday",
    "Tuesday",
    "Wednesday",
    "Thursday",
    "Friday",
    "Saturday",
  ];

  final subjects = [
    "Maths",
    "Hindi",
    "English",
    "Chemistry",
    "History",
    "Geography",
  ];

  late ScrollController mainController;

  late ScrollController secondController;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    secondController = ScrollController();

    mainController = ScrollController()
      ..addListener(() {
        if (mainController.hasClients && secondController.hasClients) {
          secondController.jumpTo(mainController.offset);
        }
      });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text("Time Table"),
      ),
      body: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
        child: PageView(
          children: [
            Column(
              mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
              children: [
                Row(
                  mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                  children: [
                    // Top header View
                    SizedBox(
                      height: containerHeight,
                      width: containerWidth,
                      child: CustomPaint(
                        painter: RectanglePainter(),
                        child: Stack(
                          children: const [
                            Align(
                              alignment: Alignment.topRight,
                              child: Padding(
                                padding: EdgeInsets.all(4.0),
                                child: Text("Day"),
                              ),
                            ),
                            Align(
                              alignment: Alignment.bottomLeft,
                              child: Padding(
                                padding: EdgeInsets.all(4.0),
                                child: Text("Period"),
                              ),
                            ),
                          ],
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                    Expanded(
                      child: SizedBox(
                        height: containerHeight,
                        child: SingleChildScrollView(
                          physics: const ClampingScrollPhysics(),
                          padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
                          scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                          controller: mainController,
                          child: Row(
                            children: List<Widget>.generate(
                              days.length,
                              (index) => Container(
                                height: containerHeight,
                                width: containerWidth,
                                color: bgColorHeader(index),
                                child: Padding(
                                  padding:
                                      const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 8),
                                  child: Center(child: Text(days[index])),
                                ),
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    )
                  ],
                ),
                SizedBox(
                  // Added fixed size to scroll listView horizontal
                  height: 500,
                  child: ListView.builder(
                    physics: const ClampingScrollPhysics(),
                    padding:
                        EdgeInsets.zero, // remove listview default padding.
                    shrinkWrap: true,
                    scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
                    itemCount: periodsSlots,
                    itemBuilder: (context, index) => Container(
                      height: containerHeight,
                      width: containerWidth,
                      color: bgColorHeader(index),
                      child: Row(
                        mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                        children: [
                          // period header
                          Padding(
                            padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
                            child: SizedBox(
                              width: containerWidth,
                              height: containerHeight,
                              child: Center(child: Text("period ${index + 1}")),
                            ),
                          ),
                          // period subjects
                          Expanded(
                            child: SizedBox(
                              height: containerHeight,
                              child: SingleChildScrollView(
                                physics: const ClampingScrollPhysics(),
                                padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
                                scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                                controller: secondController,
                                child: Row(
                                  children: List<Widget>.generate(
                                    subjects.length,
                                    (index) => Container(
                                      color: Colors.white,
                                      child: Container(
                                        height: containerHeight,
                                        width: containerWidth,
                                        color: bgColorSubject(index),
                                        child: Center(
                                            child: Padding(
                                          padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                                              horizontal: 4),
                                          child: Text(subjects[index]),
                                        )),
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                ),
                              ),
                            ),
                          )
                        ],
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                )
              ],
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  // Alternate background colors
  Color bgColorHeader(int index) =>
      index % 2 == 0 ? Colors.cyan.withOpacity(0.5) : Colors.cyanAccent;

  Color bgColorSubject(int index) =>
      index % 2 == 0 ? Colors.grey.withOpacity(0.5) : Colors.grey;
}

// Draw cross line from top left container
class RectanglePainter extends CustomPainter {
  @override
  void paint(Canvas canvas, Size size) {
    final backgroundPaint = Paint()
      ..color = Colors.cyanAccent
      ..strokeWidth = 2.0
      ..strokeCap = StrokeCap.round;

    final crossLine = Paint()
      ..color = Colors.white
      ..strokeWidth = 2.0
      ..strokeCap = StrokeCap.round;

    // Draw the rectangle
    canvas.drawRect(Offset.zero & size, backgroundPaint);

    // Draw the cross line
    canvas.drawLine(Offset.zero, Offset(size.width, size.height), crossLine);
    //canvas.drawLine(Offset(0, size.height), Offset(size.width, 0), crossLine);
  }

  @override
  bool shouldRepaint(RectanglePainter oldDelegate) => false;
}
```

[image]

Comment: Good example, but 2 problem detected. Problem1. Horizontal scrolling not working on subject list. Problem2. Below error occurs on scrolling   {  ======== Exception caught by animation library =====================================================
The following assertion was thrown while notifying listeners for AnimationController:
ScrollController attached to multiple scroll views.
'package:flutter/src/widgets/scroll_controller.dart':
Failed assertion: line 108 pos 12: '_positions.length == 1' }

Comment: Vertical scrolling is working with both period & subject and both in sync, but horizontal scrolling works only on day header(in sync with subject).

Comment: update my entire code. i am not getting error in above code. you will get error only if  you add addListener() for both mainController & secondController.

Comment: Now horizontal scrolling is working with a single row on subject grid and not in sync with day header.Please see picture 2 on question.I Still getting error while scrolling, I didn't added anything to ur code.

Comment: U added RectanglePainter method twice in ur code.

Comment: yes, removed duplicate code. i am try to generate error  but not getting error.
only error is occurring if i assigning scroll listener to both   scroll controller.